# C Program that takes a character and file names as command line arguments and keeps count of that character in each file

Tags: c, file-io, input, output, command-line-arguments

I'm fairly new to C and i've been stuck on this problem for a few hours now. Basically I'm trying to develop a program that takes a character and zero of more file names as command-line arguments. If no arguments follow the characters, have the program read the standard input. else, have it open each file in turn and report how many times the character appears in each file to an output file. Here's my code and i'm not very sure if my whole logic is correct for this program. Here's my code so far:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
FILE *in = stdin;
FILE *out = stdout;
//FILE *hold;
int j,c, count[NUM] ={0}, total =0;

for(j=1;j<argc;j++){
    if(argv[j][0] == '-'){
        if(argv[j][1] == 'o'){
            if(argv[j][2] == '\0')
                out = fopen(argv[j++],"w");
            else
                out = fopen((argv[j] +2),"w");
        }
    } else {
    in = fopen(argv[j],"r");
}
while((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF){
    count[c]++;
    total++;
}

if(fclose(in) != 0)
    fprintf(stderr,"error in closing file %s\n", argv[1]);
getchar();
return 0;}
```

I did solve a few other command line argument practices with no problems but this one seems to be a bit harder for my current level in C. Thank you for your help

Comment: This may not solve your problem, but it'll make it easier. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getopt.html

Comment: Is your program working? If not, what is it doing wrong? Please stick to specific questions ... SO is not for general code review.

Comment: At the very least you have to change `argv[j++]` in your `fopen` line to `argv[++j]`. Currently, you are always creating a file named "-o" and skipping the given filename.

Comment: Oh, and what are you *doing* with that outfile? Nothing. Aren't you supposed to?